# select image with name from src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this image src:

```
  var src="..\Uploades\SliderImg\1 (1).jpg";
```

That have space in image name `1'space'(1).jpg`

Now i wanna remove this by following code , but it not work

```
$("div.slider-image-holder img[src$='" + src + "'").fadeOut('slow', function() { 
  $(this).remove(); 
})
```

How i can select image by image name from src?

Comment: Want to remove space or image?

Comment: What do you want to remove, specifically?

Comment: What you use in your `src` variable? a number like 1,2,3... ? What's the downside of having space you want to avoid?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak i wanna remove image

Comment: @AndersonGreen iwanna remove image

Answer (score 1):

To remove the space from the `img`'s `src` property I'd suggest:

```
$('img').prop('src', function(i,oldSrc){
    return oldSrc.replace(/\s/g,'');
});
```

If, however, you want to select the `img` elements by the `src` which contains white-space, and then remove those `img` elements:

```
$('img[src="' + urlEncode(src) + '"]').remove();
```